# C# Reflection unable to find NUnit attributes

Tags: c#, reflection, nunit

Using C# on the .NET 4.5 Framework with Visual Studio 2015, I'm attempting to use Reflection to find NUnit tests and testcases from a provided .dll file. The problem I'm running into is that reflection query methods (such as `IsDefined` and `GetCustomAttributes`) require that attributes directly inherit from `System.Attribute`.

In NUnit 3.2.1 (Latest stable version as of June 2016), attributes inherit from an `NUnitAttribute` class, which in turn inherits from `System.Attribute`. This prevents Reflection from finding marked NUnit tests. As a temporary work around, I've downgraded to NUnit 2.6.4 where attributes directly inherit from `System.Attribute`. In the future, I would like to build in support for newer versions of NUnit.

Does anyone have solutions or suggestions for this issue? I've searched around, but cannot seem to find a way to make Reflection methods "realize" that `System.Attribute` is further up the inheritance chain.

Comment: I can get the custom attributes from an nUnit 3.2.1 fixture and methods without issue.  Might want to post your code.

Comment: Turns out I had mismatched versions of NUnit. Tests were being uploaded with version 3.2.1 but the system using reflection had 2.6.4. Backwards compatibility is a different question, so I'll mark this as closed and open a new thread. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As noted in reply to dbugger's comment, I had mismatched versions of NUnit between the uploaded tests and the system using reflection. I will open a new thread about backwards compatibility in this situation, found here: [Backwards compatibility with C# Reflection and NUnit Versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37995181/backwards-compatibility-with-c-sharp-reflection-and-nunit-versions)